# Error convert string "10 000.00" to double in Java

Tags: java, string, format, double

I try to convert this string "10 000.00" to double with method `Double.valueOf` and I've a input format error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10 000.00"
```

How to convert it to double?

Comment: You cannot have spaces in the numerical string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
Double.valueOf(input.replaceAll("[ ]",""));
```

in order to remove spaces before trying to convert.

**Example** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.print(Double.valueOf("10 000.00".replaceAll("[ ]","")));
}
```

**Output** :

```
10000.0
```

Comment: Works on my machine... Does your String includes the `"`characters ?

Comment: System.out.println(test); 
test = test.replaceAll("[ ]",""); 
System.out.println(test);  

Output :inline 
10 000.00 inline 
10 000.00

Comment: Yes, i've 10 000.00 in output, it's not empty

Comment: Can you show me the output of `for(char c : test.toCharArray()) {System.out.print((int) c+",");}` please?

Comment: I try to do this : replace(",", "."); i works fine, but when i try to replace space , doesn't work

Comment: 49,48,160,48,48,48,46,48,48

Comment: Ok, your space is not a space :) It is a `non-breaking space` (&nbsp; in HTML, ASCII 160) That's why the replacement is not done. Now, let's find how to replace this character with nothing

Comment: i've found solution with this : replaceAll("\u00A0","")

Comment: Thank's for all developers :)

Comment: @tchiko Can you please try my way? I tried and it works fine with special-space :D. Remember to upvote if it also works for you :D. Thank in advance! +1 for your answer

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "10 000.00"
```

*you have space in your input String "10 000.00"*

*Use following code to remove the Space from your* `String`

```
Double.valueOf("10 000.00".replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", "")) // also Works with Special space like \u00A0
```

Answer (score 3):

I see the **special-space** in your input in the comments above. I think my code will help resolve :D

```
String number = input.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", "");
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you have space between `10` and `000`. Remove it before conversion.

Try to add `replaceAll`:

```
Double.valueOf(str.replaceAll("[ ]+",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Double.parse(String); //
```

It is static method of Double class will take a string and return a double value.
Hope it help